# An easy riddle for riddlers

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I'm here on purpose.

I don't walk, run or fly.

I'm not usually the answer.

I vex the unforgiving once they know me.

I'm not blue or green or yellow.

I'm a ___ _______.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> Red Herring?

I'm here on purpose.

> Purposely put in to throw riddlers off

I don't walk, run or fly.

> Herrings swim

I'm not usually the answer.

> A red herring is usually a decoy, not the answer.

I vex the unforgiving once they know me.

> Red herrings usually appear to be the obvious answer and some people get annoyed when it's something different.

I'm not blue or green or yellow.

> I'm **Red**

I'm a ___ _______.

> As pointed out by Jon Mark Perry, the number of underscores matches the number of missing letters in each word.

Comment: Spot on.  Will except when able.  Little too easy? :)

Comment: and it's 3/7 like the underscores

Comment: @Brent Hackers By sheer coincidence, I had a thought a couple of days ago of trying to construct a riddle which had this answer so it jumped out at me when I saw yours.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Well I did say it would be easy.  Just a bit of fun that popped into my head.

Comment: @Hexomino Great!  I didn't expect it to be the first and it probably won't be the last.